# android.support.v4.widget.AppCompatTextView-Auto resizing

Tags: android

I want to make autosized `TextView.`
I have tried this:

```
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textview, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM);
```

I am trying to find a way to do the same thing in my overwritten class

```
public class BaronNeoTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{


public BaronNeoTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public BaronNeoTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public BaronNeoTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/Baron Neue Bold.otf");
    setTypeface(tf, 1);
}}
```

Here is my xml code

```
<com.lamba.valka.BaronNeoTextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:text="25"
            android:textColor="#D9D9ED"
            android:textSize="100dp" />
```

**Problem**:
How can I make one class that has this autosize method, without having to write code for every textview in every activity to autoresize using above code.

Support version v7 doesn't support auto resizing but support.v4 does and I can't extend from it.

Comment: what's a problem?

Comment: You can use font resources instead of overriding textview: [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

Comment: your class extends `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` So it will inherit it  . Whats the problem ?